# Angular ng-hide cannot find controller scope method

Tags: ng-hide

I have code in the app.js as follows:

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    controller: 'indexController',
    templateUrl: local.RootPath + '/App/Views/index.html'
});
```

In the specified controller I have a method as follows:

```
$scope.isRendering = function () {
    return _isRendering;
};
```

Finally in the index.html I have something like this:

```
<div ng-hide="isRendering">
    Here is some code...
</div>
```

So, the issue is that the ng-hide has no idea what "isRendering" is. I mean, it's in the controllers scope but it appears as though something is out of scope. If I physically set the ng-hide to false then the div content shows up. The "isRendering: is indeed false within the scope but its not coming through so the ng-hide can see it.

Any ideas what I may check?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Hum, just figured it out. Looks like I need to specify the ng-hide as follows:

ng-hide="isRendering()" since it is a function. Geez :-(